# Magical items after all charges used

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Running a campaign for the first time (first time for players and for me) and of course I am running Lost Mine of Phandelver. My players are about to confront Glasstaff and I had a question about the staff of defense he holds. 
Do players and their characters know that if they use up all the item's charges there is a chance it will be destroyed?
I am writing the item description on the card to give to the player and I wasn't sure if if should include the "roll a d20 after all charges, if 1 item destroyed".

I suppose there are 3 ways:

1. They know immediately upon attuning.
2. They can take it to someone to know more about it
3. They will never find out until the day they roll that 1

**How should the players find out about this property in magic items?**

Comment: Great question and duplicates are a-okay here! If the linked question doesn't help you, please us know and we can help clarify the difference and reopen if necessary.

Comment: The 'duplicate' doesn't really answer the question. Do players know about charges.  I think they do - I think it's commonly understood that wands have charges, and that wands explode when the last one is used.  It's something you, the DM, tell the player when they attune (short rest) or identify (spell).

Comment: Here it is: DMG 141:
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103986/does-a-wand-user-know-how-many-charges-remain